# Find matrix satisfying conditions

Tags: matlab, matrix, linear-programming

I'm looking to solve the following problem in MATLAB, but don't know which command to use.

> Find a matrix B, s.t. A * B = I and 0 <= B*a <= b

Where A and B are matrices and a and b are vectors. I is the identity matrix.

Any idea what to use? `fsolve` didn't work and I don't know how to formulate this in `linprog`.

Example:

```
A = [1 0 -1; 0 1 1];
a = [8; 6];
b = [15; 10; 10];
```

Solution using cvx:

```
cvx_begin
variable B(3,2)
min (B)
subject to
    A*B == diag(ones(2,1));
    0 <= B*a;
    b >= B*a;
cvx_end
```

Comment: could you provide some minimum reproducible example for your `A`, `a` and `b`?

Comment: Thank you, I added an example. The actual problem is very large.

Comment: There is at least one solution: `B = [1 0; 0 1; 0 0]`, that can be found without using matlab

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In order to solve those problem with `linprog` you have to list:

- The equalities
- The unequalities

So we have six unknowns:

```
B = [x1 x2
     x3 x4
     x5 x6]
```

**The unequalities are:**

[image]

and

[image]

In the format supported by `linprog` `(A*x <= b)` that give us:

```
A = [8  6  0  0  0  0
     0  0  8  6  0  0
     8  6  0  0  8  6
    -8 -6  0  0  0  0
     0  0 -8 -6  0  0
     0  0  0  0 -8 -6];

b = [15 10 10 0 0 0]
```

noticed that in order to transform the `>=0` in `<=0` have multiplied both side by `-1`.

**The equalities are:**

[image]

In the format supported by `linprog` `(Aeq*x == beq)` that give us:

```
Aeq = [1  0  0  0 -1  0
       0  1  0  0  0 -1
       0  0  1  0  1  0
       0  0  0  1  0  1]

beq = [1 0 0 1]
```

We can consider that all the variable have the same "weight", our objective function can be defined by `f = [1 1 1 1 1 1]`. But it will also work (and will provide another solution) if you change those weights. You can see this as the shape of your 6D space where some dimension can be compressed or stretched out (but not bended). For example `f = [1 0.25 1 1 -1 1/2]` is also an option...

```
f = [1 1 1 1 1 1] %which correspond to [x1 x2 x3 x4 x5 x6]

s = linprog(f, A,b,Aeq,beq,-10,10) %solve the problem with arbitrary lower and upper boundary.
```

**One possible result:**

```
s = [ 10
     -12 
      9
      13 
      9 
     -12]
```

Which give:

```
B = [10 -12
     9   13
     9   -12]
```

**Automation for larger problem:**

```
% B Matrix size
s1 = 3;
s2 = 2;

% Variable
A  = [1 0 -1; 0 1 1];
B  = sym('X', [s1 s2])
ax = [8; 6];
bx = [15; 10; 10];

% Convert linear equations to matrix form
[Aeq,beq] = equationsToMatrix(A*B == eye(s2))
[A1,b1]   = equationsToMatrix(B*ax == bx)
[A2,b2]   = equationsToMatrix(-B*ax == 0)

% Solve the problem
%      (      f      ,          A            ,            b           ,       Aeq  ,      beq  ,  lb,ub)
linprog(ones(s1*s2,1),[double(A1);double(A2)], [double(b1);double(b2)], double(Aeq),double(beq), -10,10)
```

Comment: Thanks, this works great for the example. Sadly not for a very large problem.

Comment: This can be automated for larger problem.

Comment: to automate you just let matlab provide rows of `a` after each other as is manually done in this example?

Comment: Check my edit, I used the `equationsToMatrix` function.

Answer (score 0):

Here are two different situations that you may encounter:

- With your equality constraint

  > A*B=I

I think you are already able to solve `B` using [Moore-Penrose inverse](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Moore%E2%80%93Penrose_inverse) of matrix, i.e., `pinv` (in MATLAB) or `ginv` (in R):

```r
B = pinv(A);
```

or

```r
B <- ginv(A)
```

Due to the uniqueness of Moore-Penrose inverse, you need to verify the solved `B` for the condition

> 0 <= B*a <= b

- If the inequality constraint is violated from using the method above, then you can try the method below (load `CVX` in MATLAB OR `CVXR` in R):

Unfortunately I don't have MATLAB in my computer but I tried `CVXR` with `R` language, which works well. Maybe you need minor syntax adaptions or translations to the MATLAB version.

Here is an example to show you how to formulate the problem:

```r
# given matrices
A <- matrix(c(1,0,-1,0,1,1),nrow = 2,byrow = TRUE)
a <- matrix(c(8,6))
b <- matrix(c(15,10,10))

# formulate optimization problem and solve it
library(CVXR)
B <- Variable(3,2)
obj <- Minimize(norm(A%*%B - diag(c(1,1)),"2"))
cons <- list(B%*%a >= 0, b>=B%*%a )
problem <- Problem(obj,cons)
res <- solve(problem)
```

such that

```r
> res$getValue(B)
            [,1]      [,2]
[1,]  0.90183254 0.6467117
[2,]  0.09816746 0.3532883
[3,] -0.09816746 0.6467117
```

Comment: Thank you for the reply. This is what I tried at first, but in this case the condition won't hold. According to my professor other solutions for B should be available and I should write code that finds B satisfying both conditions.

Comment: @Sniep I think you can use `cvx` to formulate the problem with both constraints and then solve `B`

Comment: Thanks, I'll give it a try

Comment: @Sniep see my update, where an example of using `CVX` to solve `B`, which works well